# SQL: Is there a more efficient way to calculate elapsed hours, minutes, seconds?

Tags: sql

I'm using Computed Columns to provide me with the following information:

Hours, Minutes, and Seconds between a Start DateTime and Finish DateTime (Where Minutes and Seconds are between 0 and 59 and Hours can be any value 0 or greater)

Computed Column for Seconds:

```
datediff(second,[Start],[Finish]) % 60
```

Computed Column for Minutes:

```
floor(datediff(second,[Start],[Finish]) / 60.0) % 60
```

Computed Column for Hours:

```
floor(datediff(second,[Start],[Finish]) / 3600.0)
```

Here's the table for reference

[image]

Note: I'm also calculating TotalElapsedSeconds, TotalElapsedMinutes, and TotalElapsedHours in other computed columns, but those are easy. I just feel like I might be missing out on a nice built in function in SQL.

Note: I have a check constraint that ensures that Finish > Start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of finding the hours, minutes, and seconds between two dates similar to the functions you are using, you could use `DatePart` like so:

```
DatePart(hh, Finish - Start)
DatePart(mi, Finish - Start)
DatePart(s, Finish - Start)
```

Comment: This answer is correct for minutes and seconds, per the details of the question -- but note that the hours (as of 5/21/2010) in the answer does not give total hours as the question intended... but this answer provides the elegant solution for grabbing the remainder minutes & seconds that I was looking for

Comment: @hamlin11 - Your calculation of hours is the total hours difference between the two datetimes but that is very different than the hours portion (or minutes or seconds) of the difference which is what I presumed you were trying to get to. If you want the difference in hours between two dates you should simply use `DateDiff(hh, Date1, Date2).` I would think you would want the three values to represent the same thing (i.e. total hours, total min, total seconds or the diff's hour portion, min portion, sec portion).

Comment: I understand where you were coming from. I was just making a distinction between your answer (what most people will come here looking for) and what my specific question was asking for. Good answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using sql server, you can use

```
datediff(minute,[Start],[Finish])
datediff(hour,[Start],[Finish])
```

Comment: This gives incorrect values for the following situation: SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'1994-01-01 11:59:59','1994-01-01 12:00:00')

Answer (score 1):

Does your dialect of SQL support this syntax for date interval math:

```
db=> select to_char(timestamp '2010-05-21 10:10:10' - '2009-10-11', 'ddd hh24:mi:ss');
   to_char    
--------------
 222 10:10:10
(1 row)

db=> select to_char(timestamp '2010-05-21 10:10:10' - '2001-10-11', 'ddd hh24:mi:ss');
    to_char    
---------------
 3144 10:10:10
(1 row)

db=> select to_char(timestamp '2010-05-21 10:10:10' - '2010-05-21', 'ddd hh24:mi:ss');
   to_char    
--------------
 000 10:10:10
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create PROC TimeDurationbetween2times(@iTime as time,@oTime as time) 
As  
Begin  

DECLARE @Dh int, @Dm int, @Ds int ,@Im int, @Om int, @Is int,@Os int     

SET @Im=DATEPART(MI,@iTime)  
SET @Om=DATEPART(MI,@oTime)  
SET @Is=DATEPART(SS,@iTime)  
SET @Os=DATEPART(SS,@oTime)  

SET @Dh=DATEDIFF(hh,@iTime,@oTime)  
SET @Dm = DATEDIFF(mi,@iTime,@oTime)  
SET @Ds = DATEDIFF(ss,@iTime,@oTime)  

DECLARE @HH as int, @MI as int, @SS as int  

if(@Im>@Om)  
begin  
SET @Dh=@Dh-1  
end  
if(@Is>@Os)  
begin  
SET @Dm=@Dm-1  
end  

SET @HH = @Dh  
SET @MI = @Dm-(60*@HH)  
SET @SS = @Ds-(60*@Dm)  

DECLARE @hrsWkd as varchar(8)         

SET @hrsWkd = cast(@HH as char(2))+':'+cast(@MI as char(2))+':'+cast(@SS as char(2))          

select @hrsWkd as TimeDuration   

End
```